# What is f in this Neural Gas neighborhood width formula?

Tags: notation, function

I'm implementing the Online Visualization Neural Gas algorithm, as described in the [Estévez, Figueroa 2006 paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Est%C3%A9vez%20Figueroa%202006%20Online%20data%20visualization%20using%20the%20neural%20gas%20network). I am having trouble interpreting the formula below (Eq. (4) in the paper):

$$\lambda(t) = \lambda_0\bigg(\frac{\lambda_f}{\lambda_0}\bigg)^{\big(\frac{t}{t_{\max}}\big)}$$

It is commented briefly as follows:

> ... the parameter $\lambda(t)$ controls the width of the neighborhood function, where $t_{\max}$ is the maximum number of adaptation steps.

I understand that $t$ is the current adaptation step. I interpret $\lambda_0$ as $\lambda(0)$, i.e. $\lambda$ during the first adaptation step.

The symbol I can't understand is $\lambda_f$.

$f$ is only mentioned in one other place in the paper, as far as I can tell, in the following formula (Eq. (6) in the paper), but that doesn't shed much light for me:

$$F(f) = e^{-\big(\frac{f}{\sigma(t)}\big)}$$

It is commented like this:

> ... $\sigma(t)$ is the width of the neighborhood that decreases with the number of iterations in the same way as Eq. (4). The function $F(f)$ is a bounded and monotonically decreasing function, in order to favor local topology preservation.

What is $\lambda_f$ and/or $f$ in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the subscript in $\lambda_f$ stands for the word *final*. Notice how $\lambda(t)=\lambda_f$ when $t = t_{max}$.

$f$ seems to bear no relation. It is just a symbol representing a "rank" and is used to define the function $F(f)$.

Comment: I meant to follow this up with a question about how to derive the values of $\lambda_0$ and $\lambda_f$, but realised that they are constants undefined by this function, just like $t_{max}$. Thanks for the help.